# The following C++ template code is showing error. Please inspect why

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile the following C++ code but its showing the errors shown in the image attached.[compiler used is visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fERM3.png). Please inspect the code and tell me what is the problem here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T>
struct MinMax {
    pair<> operator()(T itrStart, T itrEnd) {
        auto max = *itrStart;
        auto min = *itrStart;
        for (auto itr = itrStart; itr != itrEnd; itr++) {
            min = *itr < min ? *itr : min;
            max = *itr > max ? *itr : max;
        }
        std::cout << min << std::endl;
        std::cout << max << std::endl;
        return { min,max };
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr{ 2,3,4,5 };
    MinMax<std::vector<int>::iterator> Z;
    std::pair<int,int> p = Z(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    std::cout << p.first << std::endl;
    std::cout << p.second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: This compiler errors are a cryptic way of saying that it doesn't recognize the type `pair` (and then trips over the rest of the function definition). Did you mean `std::pair` and check your includes?

Comment: The template arguments of the return type `std::pair` needs to be specified. Personally i'd just use `auto` as the return type and do `return std::make_pair(min, max)`.

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that you've not specified any template argument for `std::pair` when using it to specify the return type of `operator()`.

To solve this you can make use of `std::make_pair` and the **placeholder type** `auto` as shown below:

```
vvvv-------------------------------------------->use auto
auto operator()(T itrStart, T itrEnd) {
        auto max = *itrStart;
        auto min = *itrStart;
        //other code here
//-------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvv------------------->use std::make_pair
        return std::make_pair( min,max );
    }
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/xqZxLfqkY).